# How to alias 'clear' to CTRL+L keystroke

Tags: alias, bash

I have a habit of issuing the `clear` command.

When I run cygwin, the package containing `clear` isn't installed and I don't have the option of installing it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is a good substitute; however, I still issue the `clear` command habitually.

I'd like to alias the `clear` keyword to issue the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> keystroke. Is this possible to achieve in the `.bashrc` file, or something of the like?

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way would just be to alias 'clear' to 'cls'.

Comment: This results in `-bash: cls: command not found`

Comment: Thats because the path to the standard windows commmand wasn't in your default path. But, the other guy sorted out the solution the right way anyway. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`clear` clears the screen simply by outputting some ANSI escapes sequences. You can do the same thing with `printf`:

```
alias clear='printf "\e[H\e[2J"'
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you, will accept answer in... 7 minutes apparently.

Comment: Would love to do the opposite. How do I get Ctrl+L='clear'?

Comment: Same as @s4l4x, in IDEA IDEs `Ctrl+L` clears everything but `$ `, but `clear` leaves the line before ie. `username@machine MINGWYN ~\go\src\github.com\PROFILE_NAME\PROJECT_NAME` which is the preferred way of clearing the emulated terminal.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for.  This one doesn't clear the terminal buffer whereas anything that is aliased to `clear` does.